# не могу подкючиться к mongodb выдает ошибку

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

index.js

```
const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors');
const mongoose  = require('mongoose');
const User = require('./models/User');

const app = express();
app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json());

mongoose.connect('mongodb+srv://admin:admin@cluster0.gvuv7hc.mongodb.net/?retryWrites=true&w=majority&appName=Cluster0');
// Connect to MongoDB database

app.post('/register', async (req, res) => {
    const {username, password} = req.body;
    const userDoc = await User.create({username, password});
    res.json(userDoc);
})

app.listen(4000);
```

User.js

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const { Schema, model} = mongoose

const UserSchema = new Schema({
    username: {type: String, required: true, min:4, unique:true},
    password: { type: String, required: true },
})

const UserModel = model('User', UserSchema)

model.exports = UserModel
```

Ошибка в консоли:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: замените `model.exports` на `module.exports` в User.js и удалите вопрос

Comment: ага увидел, сейчас попробую отправить запрос

Comment: теперь вот такая ошибка:
/Users/alekseyabashkin/node_modules/mongoose/lib/drivers/node-mongodb-native/collection.js:186
          const err = new MongooseError(message);
                      ^

MongooseError: Operation `users.insertOne()` buffering timed out after 10000ms
    at Timeout.<anonymous> (/Users/alekseyabashkin/node_modules/mongoose/lib/drivers/node-mongodb-native/collection.js:186:23)
    at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:573:17)
    at process.processTimers (node:internal/timers:514:7)
Node.js v21.1.0
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting

Comment: Could not connect to any servers in your MongoDB Atlas cluster. One common reason is that you're trying to access the database from an IP that isn't whitelisted. Make sure your current IP address is on your Atlas cluster's IP whitelist: https://www.mongodb.com/docs/atlas/security-whitelist/

Comment: с впна сайт работает, только подключиться никак

Comment: в общем, напишите в коннекте обработчик ошибок типа такого https://pastebin.com/d1dRwW1V и читайте что вам напишет мангус после запуска приложения. емнип, впн не нужен если ip добавлен в whitelist. но для кластера я не знаю есть ли какая-то специфика

Comment: все заработало, нашел где надо для кластера добавить ip в whitelist, и запросы начали проходить, спасибо большое

Answer (score 0):

Нужно добавить ip в whitelist в кластере mongodb